# What do these various pieces of syntax mean?

Tags: perl, parsing, sed

I'm trying to figure out the syntax of both the sed command and perl script:

```
sed 's/^EOR:$//' INPUTFILE |
perl -00 -ne '/
TAGA01:\s+(.*?)\n
.*
TAGCC08:\s+(.*?)\n
# and so on
/xs && print "$1 $2\n"'
```

Why is there a circumflex `^` in the sed command? The third slash `/` will replace all instances of `EOR:` with a blank line, correct?

I understand some of the Perl script. Looking at [`perlrun`](http://p3rl.org/run), `-00` will *slurp* the stream in paragraph mode and `-n` starts a `while <>` loop.

Why is there the first slash `/` next to the apostrophe? The command searches for `TAGXXXX:`, but I am not sure what `\s+(.*?)` does.  Does that put whatever is after the tag into a variable?  How about the `.*` in the between tag searches? What does `/ns` do? What do the `$1` and `$2` refer to in the print line?

This was tough to find online, and if someone could kick me in the right direction, I'd appreciate it.

Comment: I guess it is really hard to figure out without knowing Perl. If you just want to know about what this script does, some could tell you, but all the questions you ask about the details... you have to learn them for yourself with a good Perl book.

Comment: "I'm trying to figure out the syntax" you already know the syntax! If you want to know what code *means*, then you are trying to figure out the *semantics*, not the syntax.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The circumflex `^` is regex for "start of line", and `$` is regex for "end of line"; so `sed` will only remove lines which contain exactly "EOR:" and nothing else.

The Perl script is basically `perl -00 -ne '/(re)g(ex)/ && print "re ex\n"'` with a big ole regex instead of the simple placeholder I put here.  In particular, the `/x` modifier allows you to split the regex over several lines.  So the first `/` is the start of the regex and the final `/` is the end of the regex and the lines in between form the regex together.

The `/s` modifier changes how Perl interprets `.` in a regex; normally it will match any character except newline, but with this option, it includes newlines as well.  This means that `.*` can match multiple lines.

`\s` matches a single whitespace character; `\s+` matches as many whitespace characters as possible, but there has to be at least one.

`(.*?)` matches an arbitrary length of string; the dot matches any character, the asterisk says zero or more of any character, and the question mark modifies the asterisk repetition operator to match as short a string as possible instead of as long a string as possible.  The parentheses cause the skipped expression to be captured in a back reference; the backrefs are named `$1`, `$2`, etc, as many as there are backreferences; the numbers correspond to the order of the opening parenthesis (so if you apply `(a(b))` to the string "ab", `$1` will be "ab" and `$2` will be "b").

Finally, `\n` matches a literal newline.  So the `(.*?)` non-greedy match will match up to the first newline, i.e. the tail of the line on which the TAGsomething was found.  (I 
imagine these are gene sequences, not "tags"?)

It doesn't really make sense to run `sed` separately; Perl would be quite capable of removing the `EOR:` lines before attempting to match the regex.

Answer (score 1):

Let's see...

1. Yes, `sed` will empty the lines with `EOR:`
2. The first `/` in the Perl script means a regexp pattern. Concretely, it is searching for a pattern in the form below
3. The regex ends with "xs", which means that the regex will match multiple lines of the input
4. The script also will print as output the strings found in the tags (see below). The `$1` and `$2` mean the elements contained in the first pair of parentheses (`$1`) and in the second (`$2`).

. The form is this one:

```
TAGA01:<spaces><string1>
<whatever here>
TAGCC00:<spaces><string2>
```

In this case, `$1` is `<string1>` and `$2` is `<string2>`.